# Como hacer que App.vue abarque todo el height de la pagina

Tags: css, html5, vue.js

Ya tuve el mismo problema el cual publiqué hace unas semanas también en este foro, y ahora me encuentro con lo mismo, porque necesito poner un footer fixed abajo, y para que quede bien entonces necesito que el componente #App.vue me coja todo el 100% (como si fuese un body de html) de la pagina.

```js
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5vh 3vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: $color-letra-negro;
  background: $color-fondo-verde !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Como veis tengo "min-height: 100%" y aun asi sigue cogiendo solo la altura segun la que necesitan los componentes.

No puedo poner el footer en el html porque el footer tiene funcionalidad con vue (además imagino que sería una mala practica).

El problema me lo encuentro muchas veces, mismamente en este repo aquí no soy capaz de poner que abarque toda la pantalla:[vue sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practising-basic-concepts-in-vue-7zb3r?fontsize=14)

```js
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

Como veis en ese ejemplo también como un padding en blanco y sin embargo le digo "padding: 0" y tampoco se quita, lo que no estoy seguro es si es el mismo problema que el mio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5vh 3vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: $color-letra-negro;
  background: $color-fondo-verde !important;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Es una opción, pero tuve que borrar el max-width de 600px, creo que ese era el error, entendi la #app como un componente de dentro y le puse max-width erróneamente...Solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Probá poniendo:

```
`html,body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}`
```

Otra opción sería:

```
`#app {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}`
```